# Signing map app with custom Keystore but debug map API key

Tags: android, debugging, google-maps

I was exporting APK to give app some friends so they can test it. When The signed app is based on Custom keystore and map debug API key, app doesn't show map tiles (just default zoom buttons and switch to my location button) for a long time, But after that it shows tiles belong to focused area. I mean shouldn't it doesn't work at all when the app is signed with a **custom keystore** when it still uses **debug API key**?

What's the exact status of the map when default buttons and the Google logo (bottom left) are shown except Map tiles? What if just default buttons are shown and not even the Google logo?

In My case (sign the app just to have an installable version) should I sign the app with default debug kestore (.android\debug.keystore) and Debug map API key that was used during development?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Android key from the api console you can use the Browser key from the api console till you are debugging and testing if you find yourself changing keystores and packages too often. That one also works perfectly well.

However for added security always package the final build with your android key.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know the Browser Key would work on android too.

Comment: Doesn't Browser key depend on default debug keystore and a custom one? that's interesting

Comment: @DummyBeginner browser key will not work with Google Maps Android API v2.

Comment: It does. I am using it in a project right now. Works perfectly. Can you direct me to documentation that states otherwise?

Comment: @MaciejGórski Thanks. What's your opinion about Samarth's last comment?

Comment: @DummyBeginner No opinion. I'm currently using key "YOUR_API_KEY" in the manifest when deploying. It works until you uninstall and then install app again. Correct key is cached.

Answer (score 1):

API key has no debug/release versions for Google Maps Android API v2. You can have the same key for debug and release signing key or multiple applications. You simply need to put multiple lines of SHA-1 and package name on the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any information about these conditions too? :  "What's the exact status of the map when default buttons and the Google logo (bottom left) are shown except Map tiles? What if just default buttons are shown and not even the Google logo?"

Comment: Also Is there any chance to edit Those API keys to add more SHA-1 and packages to that key? Although I don't think so, according to essence of API key but just asking.

Comment: @DummyBeginner You can edit and add sha;package pair any time. I haven't tried to find reasons for these two cases if they both really occur.